# GPG Agent under Windows as SSH Agent for git bash

Tags: windows, ssh, git, gnupg, msysgit

I'm trying to set up gpg-agent as the common authentication agent under Windows. It works fine for both Putty and regular gpg use, but now I'd like to use it as ssh-agent in git bash as well.

From what I've gathered, it should be sufficient to use

```
export GPG_AUTH_SOCK=~/AppData/Roaming/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh
export GPG_AGENT_PID=$$
```

I can't use the real agent PID here, because the abstraction layer will hide processes outside the msys environment, so I use the shell's PID.

The gpg agent has been started with the `enable-ssh-support` and `enable-putty-support` options, and the agent socket is properly created. However, `ssh-add` claims that it cannot connect to the agent.

What is the correct way to introduce the running gpg-agent as the ssh agent into a new git bash?

Comment: How are you starting/launching this "new git bash"?

Comment: Either way behaves the same -- context menu on folder, start menu, ... I get the same behaviour running git from cmd.exe directly (in which case I use `set` to create the environment variables).

Comment: @SimonRichter, did you make any progress with this? I've been trying to start the gpg-agent daemon through git bash on Windows, but it fails miserable with: ERR 67109139 Unknown IPC command <GPG Agent>. Did you get that error too?